# Fine Uploader Invalid Response

Tags: php, cors, fine-uploader

Current Page: http://www.typhooncloud.com/fineuploader

When attempting to upload a simple jpg file, i receive the error:

'Invalid policy document or request headers!'

Here is my index.html, s3handler.php, CORS policy and console output after attempting an upload.

All changes that had been recommended have been made.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <link href="http://typhooncloud.com/fineuploader/fineuploader-3.9.0-3.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head> 
    <body>

        <!-- The element where Fine Uploader will exist. -->
        <div id="fine-uploader">
       </div>

        <!-- jQuery version 1.10.x (if you are using the jQuery plugin -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- Fine Uploader-jQuery -->
        <script src="http://typhooncloud.com/fineuploader/s3.jquery.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function ()
            {
                $('#fine-uploader').fineUploaderS3({
                    debug: true,

                    request: {
                        endpoint: "getalink1001.s3.amazonaws.com",
                        accessKey: "MYACCESSKEY"
                    },
                    signature: {
                        endpoint: "http://typhooncloud.com/fineuploader/s3handler.php"
                    },
                    uploadSuccess: {
                        endpoint: "http://typhooncloud.com/fineuploader/s3handler.php?success"
                    },
                    iframeSupport: {
                        localBlankPagePath: "http://typhooncloud.com/fineuploader/success.html"
                    },
                    validation: {
                        allowedExtensions: ["gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png"],
                        acceptFiles: "image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png",
                        sizeLimit: 5000000,
                        itemLimit: 3
                    },
                    retry: {
                        showButton: true
                    },
                    chunking: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    resume: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    deleteFile: {
                        enabled: true,
                        method: "POST",
                        endpoint: "http://typhooncloud.com/fineuploader/s3handler.php"
                    },
                    paste: {
                        targetElement: $(document),
                        promptForName: true
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

SERVER:

```
    <?php
    /**
     * PHP Server-Side Example for Fine Uploader S3.
     * Maintained by Widen Enterprises.
     *
     * Note: This is the exact server-side code used by the S3 example
     * on fineuploader.com.
     *
     * This example:
     *  - handles both CORS and non-CORS environments
     *  - handles delete file requests for both DELETE and POST methods
     *  - Performs basic inspections on the policy documents and REST headers before signing them
     *  - Ensures again the file size does not exceed the max (after file is in S3)
     *  - signs policy documents (simple uploads) and REST requests
     *    (chunked/multipart uploads)
     *
     * Requirements:
     *  - PHP 5.3 or newer
     *  - Amazon PHP SDK (only if utilizing the AWS SDK for deleting files or otherwise examining them)
     *
     * If you need to install the AWS SDK, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/installation.html.
     */

    // You can remove these two lines if you are not using Fine Uploader's
    // delete file feature
    require("aws/aws-autoloader.php");

    use Aws\S3\S3Client;


    // These assume you have the associated AWS keys stored in
    // the associated system environment variables
    $clientPrivateKey = $_SERVER['MYSECRETKEY'];
    // These two keys are only needed if the delete file feature is enabled
    // or if you are, for example, confirming the file size in a successEndpoint
    // handler via S3's SDK, as we are doing in this example.
    $serverPublicKey = $_SERVER['MYPRIVATEKEY'];
    $serverPrivateKey = $_SERVER['MYSECRETKEY'];

    // The following variables are used when validating the policy document
    // sent by the uploader: 
    $expectedBucketName = "getalink1001";
    // $expectedMaxSize is the value you set the sizeLimit property of the 
    // validation option. We assume it is `null` here. If you are performing
    // validation, then change this to match the integer value you specified
    // otherwise your policy document will be invalid.
    // http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/develop/api/options.html#validation-option
    $expectedMaxSize = 15000000;

    $method = getRequestMethod();

    // This first conditional will only ever evaluate to true in a
    // CORS environment
    if ($method == 'OPTIONS') {
        handlePreflight();
    }
    // This second conditional will only ever evaluate to true if
    // the delete file feature is enabled
    else if ($method == "DELETE") {
        handleCorsRequest(); // only needed in a CORS environment
        deleteObject();
    }
    // This is all you really need if not using the delete file feature
    // and not working in a CORS environment
    else if ($method == 'POST') {
        handleCorsRequest();

        // Assumes the successEndpoint has a parameter of "success" associated with it,
        // to allow the server to differentiate between a successEndpoint request
        // and other POST requests (all requests are sent to the same endpoint in this example).
        // This condition is not needed if you don't require a callback on upload success.
        if (isset($_REQUEST["success"])) {
            verifyFileInS3();
        }
        else {
            signRequest();
        }
    }

    // This will retrieve the "intended" request method.  Normally, this is the
    // actual method of the request.  Sometimes, though, the intended request method
    // must be hidden in the parameters of the request.  For example, when attempting to
    // send a DELETE request in a cross-origin environment in IE9 or older, it is not
    // possible to send a DELETE request.  So, we send a POST with the intended method,
    // DELETE, in a "_method" parameter.
    function getRequestMethod() {
        global $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;

        // This should only evaluate to true if the Content-Type is undefined
        // or unrecognized, such as when XDomainRequest has been used to
        // send the request.
        if(isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) {
          parse_str($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, $_POST);
        }

        if ($_POST['_method'] != null) {
            return $_POST['_method'];
        }

        return $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    }

    // Only needed in cross-origin setups
    function handleCorsRequest() {
        // If you are relying on CORS, you will need to adjust the allowed domain here.
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://typhoonupload.com');
    }

    // Only needed in cross-origin setups
    function handlePreflight() {
        handleCorsRequest();
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
    }

    function getS3Client() {
        global $serverPublicKey, $serverPrivateKey;

        return S3Client::factory(array(
            'key' => $serverPublicKey,
            'secret' => $serverPrivateKey
        ));
    }

    // Only needed if the delete file feature is enabled
    function deleteObject() {
        getS3Client()->deleteObject(array(
            'Bucket' => $_POST['bucket'],
            'Key' => $_POST['key']
        ));
    }

    function signRequest() {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');

        $responseBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $contentAsObject = json_decode($responseBody, true);
        $jsonContent = json_encode($contentAsObject);

        $headersStr = $contentAsObject["headers"];
        if ($headersStr) {
            signRestRequest($headersStr);
        }
        else {
            signPolicy($jsonContent);
        }
    }

    function signRestRequest($headersStr) {
        if (isValidRestRequest($headersStr)) {
            $response = array('signature' => sign($headersStr));
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
        else {
            echo json_encode(array("invalid" => true));
        }
    }

    function isValidRestRequest($headersStr) {
        global $expectedBucketName;

        $pattern = "/\/$expectedBucketName\/.+$/";
        preg_match($pattern, $headersStr, $matches);

        return count($matches) > 0;
    }

    function signPolicy($policyStr) {
        $policyObj = json_decode($policyStr, true);

        if (isPolicyValid($policyObj)) {
            $encodedPolicy = base64_encode($policyStr);
            $response = array('policy' => $encodedPolicy, 'signature' => sign($encodedPolicy));
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
        else {
            echo json_encode(array("invalid" => true));
        }
    }

    function isPolicyValid($policy) {
        global $expectedMaxSize, $expectedBucketName;

        $conditions = $policy["conditions"];
        $bucket = null;
        $parsedMaxSize = null;

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($conditions); ++$i) {
            $condition = $conditions[$i];

            if (isset($condition["bucket"])) {
                $bucket = $condition["bucket"];
            }
            else if (isset($condition[0]) && $condition[0] == "content-length-range") {
                $parsedMaxSize = $condition[2];
            }
        }

        return $bucket == $expectedBucketName && $parsedMaxSize == (string)$expectedMaxSize;
    }

    function sign($stringToSign) {
        global $clientPrivateKey;

        return base64_encode(hash_hmac(
                'sha1',
                $stringToSign,
                $clientPrivateKey,
                true
            ));
    }

    // This is not needed if you don't require a callback on upload success.
    function verifyFileInS3() {
        global $expectedMaxSize;

        $bucket = $_POST["bucket"];
        $key = $_POST["key"];

        // If utilizing CORS, we return a 200 response with the error message in the body
        // to ensure Fine Uploader can parse the error message in IE9 and IE8,
        // since XDomainRequest is used on those browsers for CORS requests.  XDomainRequest
        // does not allow access to the response body for non-success responses.
        if (getObjectSize($bucket, $key) > $expectedMaxSize) {
            // You can safely uncomment this next line if you are not depending on CORS
            //header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
            deleteObject();
            echo json_encode(array("error" => "File is too big!"));
        }
        else {
            echo json_encode(array("tempLink" => getTempLink($bucket, $key)));
        }
    }

    // Provide a time-bombed public link to the file.
    function getTempLink($bucket, $key) {
        $client = getS3Client();
        $url = "{$bucket}/{$key}";
        $request = $client->get($url);

        return $client->createPresignedUrl($request, '+15 minutes');
    }

    function getObjectSize($bucket, $key) {
        $objInfo = getS3Client()->headObject(array(
                'Bucket' => $bucket,
                'Key' => $key
            ));
        return $objInfo['ContentLength'];
    }
    ?>
```

The CORS buckey policy is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
        <CORSRule>
            <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
            <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
            <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
            <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
            <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
            <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
            <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
        </CORSRule>
    </CORSConfiguration>
```

Chrome console:

```
      [FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Received 1 files or inputs. s3.jquery.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.js:164
      [FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Submitting S3 signature request for 0 s3.jquery.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.js:164
      [FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending POST request for 0 s3.jquery.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.js:164
      [FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Invalid policy document or request headers! s3.jquery.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.js:169
      [FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Policy signing failed.  Invalid policy document or request headers! s3.jquery.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.js:169
      [FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Received response status 0 with body:  s3.jquery.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.js:164
      [FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Upload attempt for file ID 0 to S3 is complete s3.jquery.fineuploader-3.9.0-3.js:164
```

Fiddler Output:

```
      POST http://typhooncloud.com/fineuploader/s3handler.php HTTP/1.1
      Host: typhooncloud.com
      Connection: keep-alive
      Content-Length: 287
      Origin: http://typhooncloud.com
      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36
      Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
      Accept: */*
      Referer: http://typhooncloud.com/fineuploader/
      Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
      Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
      Cookie: __utma=33700260.900109978.1379619256.1379708113.1380038992.6; __utmb=33700260.1.10.1380038992; __utmc=33700260; __utmz=33700260.1380038992.6.2.utmcsr=stackoverflow.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/questions/18971119/fine-uploader-invalid-response
      AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH: AlexaToolbar/alxg-3.2

      {"expiration":"2013-09-24T16:26:35.948Z","conditions":[{"acl":"private"},{"bucket":"getalink1001"},{"Content-Type":"image/gif"},{"success_action_status":"200"},{"key":"f7e280c4-8cae-4bd7-82c4-d19e71186def.gif"},{"x-amz-meta-qqfilename":"319.gif"},["content-length-range","0","5000000"]]}


      HTTP/1.1 200 OK
      Date: Tue, 24 Sep 2013 16:21:49 GMT
      Server: Apache
      Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://typhoonupload.com
      Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
      Connection: Keep-Alive
      Transfer-Encoding: chunked
      Content-Type: application/json

      10
      {"invalid":true}
      0
```

Comment: You'll have to provide more information than this.  It looks like you've simply copy and pasted one of the provided server side examples.  Are you even working in a cross origin environment?  Let's start with the contents of the browsers developer console with the debug option enabled.

Comment: I have included above the 'console output', you can of course try it yourself live if you would like, thank you in advance.

Comment: Edit your question to include the console output with the debug option set to true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like when you copy and pasted the PHP example server code, you neglected to adjust some of the values.  In this case, the `handlePreflightedRequest` method was not modified to reflect your domain.

It should read:

```php
function handlePreflightedRequest() {
    // If you are relying on CORS, you will need to adjust the allowed domain here.
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://typhooncloud.com');
}
```

Also, the `handlePreflightedRequest` method should probably be renamed `handleCorsRequest` to avoid confusion.  I've done this just now in the server repo.  You don't really need to do this though, as it won't affect the behavior of the code.

Comment: Made changes as seen above, still same result.

Comment: You have also incorrectly modified the `handlePreflight` method.  Remove the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE` lines.  Not only is it incorrect to write this header more than once per response, Fine Uploader will only ever send POST requests to your signature server, assuming you are following the example code on fineuploader.com (which appears to be the case).

Comment: ok, i had only added those additional headers in an attempt to get it working, since without them it was not...  please see the new response console output, and the new file itself... thank you for your help

Comment: You cannot use a wildcard as a value for the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header in your response.  The spec does not allow this.  I strongly suggest you take some time to read the Fine Uploader S3 documentation & blog post (and the CORS documentation for Fine Uploader and associated blog post) if you intend to deviate from the examples instead of taking these continued stabs in the dark.  The example contained an entry for the expected Content-Type header.  You commented it out, and then removed it.  Even if wildcards were allowed, you should not be using them in most cases.

Comment: ...since you are working in a cross-origin environment, you will need to have at least a basic understanding of the same origin policy and the CORS spec.  I've blogged about this on the Fine Uploader blog and linked to a must-read article that describes the CORS requirements.  However, the server-side PHP example really does all of this for you.  All you need to do is adjust a few values.  If you need to make more drastic changes (and it doesn't seem like your situation warrants this), you will need to take some time to familiarize yourself with the associated concepts first.

Comment: ...So, in closing: start over with the provided PHP example and only modify the fields in the s3demo-cors.php file that must be modified to suit your situation.  The file has detailed comments that indicate exactly what needs to be done.

Comment: I have been working to get fine uploader to work since Friday.  I have read nearly every line of your documentation.  I understand the concepts involved, but purchasing your product was done so I could avoid 3 days of debugging.  I solely programmed all of TyphoonCloud.Com, before there were any SDK kits. All my C++ code was written by scratch, building headers, signing requests, including sending signing requests to our server to perform POSTs, and this was back in 2008.  Please review all the new changes, I am still getting an error, I am obviously missing something. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can also get a peek at what our online s3 portal looks like http://www.typhooncloud.com , there is a live demo on the front page.  All static web pages served solely from S3, using JQuery and a lot of ajax calls to load XML to represent the pages, all of which are encrypted and require on the fly decryption via JavaScript, we were forced to do this before CORS support was offered, no Java, no Flash, no 3rd server for any processing, all static, all created and uploaded by the software. Just FYI.

Comment: What does the response to the signature request look like?  It appears to be empty based on the log message.  Clearly, there is some issue in your code that is preventing your server from returning the proper response to the signature request.

Comment: Is there some twist having to do with www.typhooncloud.com vs typhooncloud.com?  Or the fact that the s3handler is in a subfolder and not immediately from the root?  Or even https vs http. Let me know if that add output above is what you were looking for.

Comment: Your server-side code is declaring the policy received by Fine Uploader invalid.  This means that your `isPolicyValid` method is returning false.  You will need to take a closer look at this method.  You didn't adjust the `$expectedMaxSize` variable in the PHP example to match your client-side code.  Please read the comment above this variable in the example code.

Comment: Thank you Ray for your help, Fine Uploader is now working.  The actual access key and secret key in the s3handler.php were not set in the SERVER environ variables.  Once I set those locally, every worked.  For future reference perhaps make sure anyone has those set specifically.  My oversight indeed, however too many variable to make it a smooth installation.  Fine Uploader is much more powerful, however in constrast I was able to get Uploadify working in less than 30 minutes.

Comment: Fine Uploader is great, thank you again. P.S.-I tackled a similar monster ages ago, try out typhoonupload.com, had to use Php+Perl+Ajax just to get the progress bar!  What a mess!  PHP would't return live upload progress data, only Perl.  Our delivery page zipped the download on the fly, cool piece of tech.  Anyways, thanks again. Oh, and all of this is because of typhoonupload, i plan on replacing it with fine uploader.

Comment: Note that Uploadify has absolutely no integrated support for direct-to-S3 uploads.  I would argue that your use case is quite advanced as you are working in a cross-origin environment.  Fine Uploader makes uploading to S3 quite simple in that you only really have to worry about signing requests.  Trying to tackle direct-to-s3 uploads that without native support from your upload library would be **significantly** more work.  Fine Uploader S3 has shielded you from the vast majority of the complexity associated with direct-to-s3 uploads.

Answer (score 1):

Side note. Let me point out a crucial difference. In the javascript code you write `sizeLimit: 5000000`, but in the PHP you write `$expectedMaxSize = 15000000`. These values must match exactly.